# Figurative usage of "(Saint) Graal"

Tags: usage, religion

In English "holy grail" renders the meaning of a distant, near impossible goal. According to https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/graal the word *graal* renders the same effect:

> (Par extension) Objet d’une quête longue et souvent vaine, à l’image de la quête du Graal dans la littérature du Moyen Âge.

Can you use colloquially *(Saint) graal* in this figurative way? For example:

> La preuve de la conjecture de Fermat a longtemps été le (Saint) graal des mathématiciens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On peut sans aucun doute se servir du terme « le Graal de …» figurativement ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graal#Sens_figur%C3%A9_du_mot)).

On peut tout aussi bien utiliser « le Saint Graal de … ».

*Trois exemples parmi beaucoup d'autres*

- L'Empereur de toutes les maladies: Une biographie du cancer
  https://books.google.fr › books
  Siddhartha Mukherjee - 2013 - ‎Aperçu - ‎Autres éditions
  En 1856, William Perkin, un étudiant de dix-huit ans de l'un de ces instituts, tomba sur ce qui allait bientôt devenir le Saint-Graal de cette industrie, un colorant chimique bon marché qui pouvait être entièrement synthétisé …
- L'utopie urbaine au XXe siècle: - Page 127
  https://books.google.fr › books
  Robert Fishman - 1979 - ‎Aperçu - ‎Autres éditions
  Il poursuivait le Saint-Graal de la 'synthèse', la combinaison d'éléments apparemment inconciliables en un tout inattendu, mais cohérent et inévitable. Si la valeur la plus haute était, pour Howard, la coopération, et pour Wright, l'individualisme …
- L’École Bousillée Au Profit De L’Establishment: Essai ...
  https://books.google.fr › books
  Roméo Gauvreau - 2014 - ‎Aperçu
  Pour eux, le contenu du programme est le Saint Graal de l'éducation. Eh bien,j'ose différerdecet avis largement partagé parmiles enseignants. Le contenu du programme devraitêtre très pertinent pourles enfants, mais estce quecela constitue ...

On trouve aussi ce terme épelé avec un trait d'union (le Saint-Graal de …).

Ce n'est pas un terme familier, mais ce n'est pas  non plus un terme trop formel pour le langage courant, d'autant plus que l'on se doit de l'employer pour des choses qui sont plutôt importantes.